# Image won't display as variable reaches certain value

Tags: javascript

I won't include all the code because it is really a lot but here is most of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title> CaroQuiz </title>

</head>

<body>

<div>


<div class="quiz"><img src="bilder/text.png">

<div class="name"> <img src="bilder/name.png"> </div>

<div class="hr"> </div>

<div class="hr2"> </div>

<div class="text2"> <img src="bilder/text2.png"> </div>

<div class="text3"> <img src="bilder/text3.png"> </div>

<div class="school"> <img src="bilder/school.jpg"> </div>

<div class="hr3"> </div>

<div class="question1"> <img src="bilder/question1.png"> </div>

<div class="text4"> <img src="bilder/text4.png"> </div>

<div class="question2"> <img src="bilder/question2.png"> </div>

<div class="text5"> <img src="bilder/text5.png"> </div>

<div class="text6"> <img src="bilder/text6.png"> </div>

<div class="question3"> <img src="bilder/question3.png"> </div>

<div class="question4"> <img src="bilder/question4.png"> </div>




<button class="button" button onclick="answerOne()"> Math </button>

<button class="button2" button onclick="answerTwo()"> Physical Education </button>

<button class="button3" button onclick="answerThree()"> History </button>

<button class="button4" button onclick="answerFour()"> Arts and crafts </button>

<button class="button5" button onclick="answerFive()"> I don't have any </button>

<button class="button6" button onclick="answerSix()"> 1-2 </button>

<button class="button7" button onclick="answerSeven()"> 3-5 </button>

<button class="button8" button onclick="answerEight()"> More than I can count </button>

<button class="button9" button onclick="answerNine()"> No </button>

<button class="button10" button onclick="answerTen()"> Yes </button>

<button class="button11" button onclick="answerEleven()"> I just ignore them </button>

<button class="button12" button onclick="answerTwelve()"> Somewhat </button>

<div class="text7"> <img src="bilder/text7.png"> </div>


</div>

<button class="button14" button onclick="answerThirteen()"> I only get A-s and B-s </button>

<button class="button15" button onclick="answerFourteen()"> I get B-s and C-s </button>

<button class="button16" button onclick="answerFifteen()"> I get D-s and E-s </button>

<button class="button17" button onclick="answerSixteen()"> I failed every subject </button>

<div class="finale"> <img src="bilder/Finale.png"> 

<button class="button18" button onclick="check()"> Yes! </button>


var poeng = 0;
                             
function answerOne() {

poeng = 200;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

function answerTwo() {

poeng = -300;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

function answerThree() {

poeng = 500;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

function answerFour() {

poeng = 600;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

function answerFive() {

if(poeng == 200) {

poeng = poeng + 0;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

else if (poeng == -300) {

poeng = poeng - 300;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

else if (poeng == 500) {

poeng = poeng - 1000;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

else if (poeng == 600) {

poeng = poeng + 0;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

function answerSix() {

if(poeng == 200) {

poeng = poeng + 0;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

else if(poeng == -300) {

poeng = poeng + 0;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

else if(poeng == 500) {

poeng = poeng + 0;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

else if(poeng == 600) {

poeng = poeng + 0;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

function check() {

if(poeng == 200) {

 document.write('<img style="position: relative; top: 500px; left: 200px;" src="bilder/cat2.jpg">');
    
 

    
 }
}
```

Okay so what is supposed to happen is that you have multiple buttons. When you press them the variable "poeng" changes. In the end there is a question asking "are you done?" then there is a button that says Yes!. Then a picture is supposed to pop up. I tried pressing the button that gives 200 points and above but nothing happens. The weird part is that it worked earlier but not anymore.

Could anyone pls help me? This is for school and I am really stressed out as to why it is not working.

- Caroline 12

Comment: Right before `function check() {` you're missing the closing bracket `}` to the previous function, which is causing all your javascript to break

Comment: and for testing, how does one get `poeng = 200`?

Comment: by pressing the first button, i tried but still nothing seems to happen..

Comment: it says there is an unrecoverable syntax error- "unexpected end of input"

Comment: yet i believe i have all the brackets

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer yet - but is a 'working' version of your code. The 'Yes' button does work, but since poeng = 0 nothing happens. What else do you need help with?

```js
var poeng = 0;

function answerOne() {

  poeng = 200;

  console.log(poeng)
  check()
}

function answerTwo() {

  poeng = -300;

  console.log(poeng)
  check()
}

function answerThree() {

  poeng = 500;

  console.log(poeng)
  check()
}

function answerFour() {

  poeng = 600;

  console.log(poeng)
  check()
}

function answerFive() {

  if (poeng == 200) {

    poeng = poeng + 0;

    console.log(poeng)
    check()
  } else if (poeng == -300) {

    poeng = poeng - 300;

    console.log(poeng)
    check()
  } else if (poeng == 500) {

    poeng = poeng - 1000;

    console.log(poeng)
    check()
  } else if (poeng == 600) {

    poeng = poeng + 0;

    console.log(poeng)
    check()
  }

  console.log(poeng)
  check()
}

function answerSix() {

  if (poeng == 200) {

    poeng = poeng + 0;

    console.log(poeng)
    check()
  } else if (poeng == -300) {

    poeng = poeng + 0;

    console.log(poeng)
    check()
  } else if (poeng == 500) {

    poeng = poeng + 0;

    console.log(poeng)
    check()
  } else if (poeng == 600) {

    poeng = poeng + 0;

    console.log(poeng)
    check()
  }
  }

  function check() {
     if (poeng == 200) {

       document.write('<img style="position: relative; top: 500px; left: 200px;" src="bilder/cat2.jpg">');




    }
  }
```

```html
  <div class="quiz"><img src="bilder/text.png">

    <div class="name"> <img src="bilder/name.png"> </div>

    <div class="hr"> </div>

    <div class="hr2"> </div>

    <div class="text2"> <img src="bilder/text2.png"> </div>

    <div class="text3"> <img src="bilder/text3.png"> </div>

    <div class="school"> <img src="bilder/school.jpg"> </div>

    <div class="hr3"> </div>

    <div class="question1"> <img src="bilder/question1.png"> </div>

    <div class="text4"> <img src="bilder/text4.png"> </div>

    <div class="question2"> <img src="bilder/question2.png"> </div>

    <div class="text5"> <img src="bilder/text5.png"> </div>

    <div class="text6"> <img src="bilder/text6.png"> </div>

    <div class="question3"> <img src="bilder/question3.png"> </div>

    <div class="question4"> <img src="bilder/question4.png"> </div>




    <button class="button" button onclick="answerOne()"> Math </button>

    <button class="button2" button onclick="answerTwo()"> Physical Education </button>

    <button class="button3" button onclick="answerThree()"> History </button>

    <button class="button4" button onclick="answerFour()"> Arts and crafts </button>

    <button class="button5" button onclick="answerFive()"> I don't have any </button>

    <button class="button6" button onclick="answerSix()"> 1-2 </button>

    <button class="button7" button onclick="answerSeven()"> 3-5 </button>

    <button class="button8" button onclick="answerEight()"> More than I can count </button>

    <button class="button9" button onclick="answerNine()"> No </button>

    <button class="button10" button onclick="answerTen()"> Yes </button>

    <button class="button11" button onclick="answerEleven()"> I just ignore them </button>

    <button class="button12" button onclick="answerTwelve()"> Somewhat </button>

    <div class="text7"> <img src="bilder/text7.png"> </div>


  </div>

  <button class="button14" button onclick="answerThirteen()"> I only get A-s and B-s </button>

  <button class="button15" button onclick="answerFourteen()"> I get B-s and C-s </button>

  <button class="button16" button onclick="answerFifteen()"> I get D-s and E-s </button>

  <button class="button17" button onclick="answerSixteen()"> I failed every subject </button>

  <div class="finale"> <img src="bilder/Finale.png">

    <button class="button18" button onclick="check()"> Yes! </button>
```

Comment: wow it worked :O i was starting to loose hope not gonna lie.

Comment: Just one thing, you see how when i press math, the image automatically shows up. What if i want to press math, and then the "Yes!" button? Because in the quiz the points are supposed to add up. :)

Comment: Don't call the `change()` function inside the other functions. Only when someone clicks `yes` button

Comment: oh oki! thank you so much for the help! i really appreaciate it :D